# GitPython Clone repository error

Tags: python, git, gitpython

I want to clone git repository with parameters (`--recursive`, `-b <branch>`) but I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./git-clone.py", line 15, in <module>
    r = git.Repo.clone(repo_dir, b=branch, recursive=git_url)
TypeError: unbound method clone() must be called with Repo instance as first argument (got str instance instead)
```

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import git
import os
import shutil


git_url = "<url>..."
repo_dir = "/home_local/user/git-repository"
branch = "branch"

if os.path.exists(repo_dir):
    shutil.rmtree(repo_dir)

r = git.Repo.clone(repo_dir, b=branch, recursive=git_url)
```

If I replace `git.Repo.clone` with `git.Repo.clone_from` its working fine but this command not accept my parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try:

```
r = git.Repo.clone_from(git_url, repo_dir, branch=branch, recursive=True)
```

The first argument, is where you cloning from (the remote repository). The second argument is where you want to store the clone. All other arguments are passed on to `git-clone` command. eg `--branch="branch"` and `--recursive`. You should probably stick to the long argument names rather than the abbreviations. Since the recursive flag is either present or not, it's values can only be True or False.